# In Flutter Widget testing, how to make media.orientation to portrait?

Tags: flutter, ui-testing

In build method, `MediaQuery.of(context).orientation` equals `Orientation.landscape`. How to make it into `portrait`.

The test widget is wrap under `MaterialApp`.

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10307

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping the widgets that query orientation in

```
  MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQueryData
        .fromWindow(ui.window)
        .copyWith(size: const Size(600.0, 800.0)),
    child: widgetToTest,
  )
```

worked for me.

`MediaQuery.orientation` just checks what dimension is bigger

```
  Orientation get orientation {
    return size.width > size.height ? Orientation.landscape : Orientation.portrait;
  }
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706569/how-to-test-flutter-widgets-on-different-screen-sizes