# How do you mock or set device width/height in Flutter Widget test?

Tags: testing, flutter, integration

I'm writing Widget tests in Flutter and need to be able to test my layouts on different device sizes.

The headless device size is always 600 height and 800 width. I want to be able to specify the size in my test. Some of the UI logic is dependant on device size and can't be tested unless I can set this size.

Comment: Maybe the question [how to make media.orientation to portrait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158364/in-flutter-widget-testing-how-to-make-media-orientation-to-portrait) can help you. The question is slightly different, but the answer is relevant. Though I realise this is not a complete answer.