# How to test Flutter widgets on different screen sizes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a Flutter widget which shows extra data depending on the screen size. Does anyone know a way of testing this widget on multiple different screen sizes?

I've had a look through the [widget_tester](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/widget_tester.dart) source code but can't find anything.

Comment: By test, you mean unit test/similar or manual test?

Comment: By test, I mean widget testing as in testing if specific widgets are visible, similar to unit tests. https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/testing/widget

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can specify custom surface size by using [WidgetTester](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester-class.html)

The following code will run a test with a screen size of 42x42

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets("foo", (tester) async {
    tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(42, 42);

    // resets the screen to its original size after the test end
    addTearDown(tester.binding.window.clearPhysicalSizeTestValue);

    // TODO: do something
  });
}
```

Comment: If a widget with Scaffold parent is under test it is required to add Material app as a wrapper like this: 
await tester.pumpWidget(new MaterialApp(home: new LoginScreen()));

Comment: What's the default size? I did 1200, 2400 and it's still smaller than the default size.

Comment: It's a width of 800 and height of 600

Comment: @RémiRousselet I followed your advice but it does not work properly with texts

Comment: @RémiRousselet check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447898/flutter-widget-test-cannot-emulate-different-screen-size-properly and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59755

Comment: You can also set the pixel density using the `devicePixelRatioTestValue` property

Comment: Proper answer now is to use `tester.binding.setSurfaceSize(size);` (see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12994#issuecomment-902964066)

Comment: tester.binding.window is deprecated from 3.9.0 This seems to work tester.view.devicePixelRatio = 1;
      tester.view.physicalSize = const Size(1200, 800);

Answer (score 37):

Not sure why but solution of @rémi-rousselet didn't work for me. I've had to specify screen size using `binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue` and `binding.window.devicePixelRatioTestValue` so that output is fully deterministic

I've added a little bit more code for flutter beginners like me. Check this:

```
void main() {

  final TestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding =
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets("Basic layout test (mobile device)", (tester) async {
    binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(400, 200);
    binding.window.devicePixelRatioTestValue = 1.0;

    await tester.pumpWidget(new MyApp());

    expect(find.byType(MyHomePage), findsOneWidget);
    // etc.
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this one worked for me (setSurfaceSize didn't).

Comment: Same here, setSurfaceSize() didn't work for me, but your solution did. Thanks.

Comment: @VizGhar I followed your advice but I does not work properly with texts check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447898/flutter-widget-test-cannot-emulate-different-screen-size-properly and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59755

Comment: adding `devicePixelRatioTestValue` works well!

Comment: For anyone who gets a type casting error when trying this, add `as TestWidgetsFlutterBinding` So the whole thing would be `final TestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding = TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() as TestWidgetsFlutterBinding;`

Answer (score 15):

There is a package called [device_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview) that can simulate your flutter app running on different devices.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Since version 3.10.0, the window singleton is deprecated( https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton). Therefore, the size must now be set as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets("foo", (tester) async {
    tester.view.physicalSize = Size(42, 42);

    // resets the screen to its original size after the test end
    addTearDown(tester.view.resetPhysicalSize);

    // TODO: do something
  });
}
```

Comment: I also had to add `tester.view.devicePixelRatio = 1.0;`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for Flutter versions above 3.10.0, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

@rémi-rousselet's solution works perfectly!

In addition if you want to test an orientation change, try this:

```
const double PORTRAIT_WIDTH = 400.0;
const double PORTRAIT_HEIGHT = 800.0;
const double LANDSCAPE_WIDTH = PORTRAIT_HEIGHT;
const double LANDSCAPE_HEIGHT = PORTRAIT_WIDTH;

final TestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding = TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

await binding.setSurfaceSize(Size(PORTRAIT_WIDTH, PORTRAIT_HEIGHT));
await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidget());

// test in portrait

await binding.setSurfaceSize(Size(LANDSCAPE_WIDTH, LANDSCAPE_HEIGHT));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();

// OrientationBuilder gets triggered

// test in landscape
```

Answer (score 7):

Currently the safest way is to use [setSurfaceSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestWidgetsFlutterBinding/setSurfaceSize.html)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets("foo", (tester) async {
    tester.binding.setSurfaceSize(Size(400, 400));

    // reset
    tester.binding.setSurfaceSize(null);

    // continue
  });
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12994#issuecomment-902964066) for related Github issue

Comment: They are planning to deprecate this. See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123881

Comment: Correct answer at this point of time would be https://stackoverflow.com/a/76415174/3302026

Answer (score 3):

Although @Rémi Rousselet's answer was very helpful it didn't completely solve my problem. It turns out that I could just wrap my widget under test in a `MediaQuery` widget and set the size.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  Widget makeTestableWidget({Widget child, Size size}) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQueryData(size: size),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }

  testWidgets("tablet", (tester) async {
    final testableWidget = makeTestableWidget(
      child: WidgetUnderTest(),
      size: Size(1024, 768),
    );

    ...
  });

  testWidgets("phone", (tester) async {
    final testableWidget = makeTestableWidget(
      child: WidgetUnderTest(),
      size: Size(375, 812),
    );

    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly true. It doesn't truly change the size, but mock MediaQuery. Things like `LayoutBuilder` or `RenderObjects`, or golden tests will still be based on the default size.

Comment: ahh ok, when I tried using TestWidgetsFlutterBinding it had no impact because in my widget, I get the screen size from the MediaQuery which was being created my the MaterialApp widget. If I remove the MaterialApp widget it throws an error about textDirection being null, so this seemed like the best option but obviously not the best option in every case.

Comment: I'd suggest marking my answer as the solution instead (unless you disagree), as mocking MediaQuery is rarely desired the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this widget to test your widgets changing screen size in realtime

**Screen Size Test**

https://pub.dev/packages/screen_size_test

**Preview**

[image]

**Demo**
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/43d9c47a8bf031ce3ef2f6314c9dbd52

**Code Sample**

```dart
import 'package:screen_size_test/screen_size_test.dart';
...
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Demo',
  builder: (context, child) => ScreenSizeTest(
    child: child,
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      children: List.generate(
          20,
          (index) => Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Placeholder(),
              )),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: slider is not wokring

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to wrap testWidgets so you do not have to make changes to all your tests when you want to add a platform or size for screen. Here is a matrix that tests some sizes and platforms:

```dart
const List<Size> _testedSizes = [
  Size(800, 600),
  Size(600, 800),
];

void testWidgetInPlatformMatrix(
  String description,
  Future<void> Function(WidgetTester) callback,
) {
  for (var size in _testedSizes) {
    testWidgets(
      '$description ($size)',
      (widgetTester) async {
        await widgetTester.binding.setSurfaceSize(size);
        return callback(widgetTester);
      },
      variant: TargetPlatformVariant.mobile(),
    );
  }
}
```

then you'd use `testWidgetInPlatformMatrix` instead of `testWidgets`:

```
testWidgetInPlatformMatrix('Counter increments smoke test',
          (WidgetTester tester) async {
  //...
});
```