# Flutter. How to test that there is no overflows with integration tests?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I use flutter_driver to do my integration tests in Flutter. On some screens text on buttons gives overflow errors. I want to create a test which can show that overflow happened. So when I will run all integration tests on a bunch of virtual/real devices I can see that UI is not positioned correctly.

Comment: Why _integration test_ specifically? This can be tested using widget tests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need for integration tests for that. Widget tests will do.

Since Widget testing runs with asserts enabled, calling `tester.pumpWidget` with a widget that would overflow will throw an exception and therefore make a failing test.

For example, the following test will fail:

```
testWidgets('overflow', (tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(Row(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    children: <Widget>[
      // too big to fit in the default size of the row
      Container(width: 99999),
    ],
  ));
});
```

Note that the screen size for widget testing can be customized. See [How to test Flutter widgets on different screen sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706569/how-to-test-flutter-widgets-on-different-screen-sizes)

Alternatively, we can wrap our tested widget into a `Container` like so:

```
await tester.pumpWidget(Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  width: <my screen widget>,
  height: <my screen height>,
  child: <the widget which I want to test overflow on>,
);
```

Comment: Using widget testing to catch Renderflex overflows is not working properly because we need to customize the screen size of the tester but the text size are not matching the real device text size. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447898/flutter-widget-test-cannot-emulate-different-screen-size-properly and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59755

Answer (score 0):

I have published 3 helper functions on my package called [`hrk_flutter_test_batteries`](https://pub.dev/packages/hrk_flutter_test_batteries).
They are as follows:

1. [`disableOverflowError()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hrk_flutter_test_batteries/latest/hrk_flutter_test_batteries/disableOverflowError.html)
2. [`tester.getOverflowRenderFlexList()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hrk_flutter_test_batteries/latest/hrk_flutter_test_batteries/HrkWidgetTester/getOverflowRenderFlexList.html)
3. [`tester.expectNoOverflow()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hrk_flutter_test_batteries/latest/hrk_flutter_test_batteries/HrkWidgetTester/expectNoOverflow.html)

You can use them as follows:

1. First import the package

```
flutter pub add dev:hrk_flutter_test_batteries
```

2. Source - [get_overflow_render_flex_list_test.dart](https://github.com/hrishikesh-kadam/hrk_flutter_test_batteries/blob/main/test/extension/widget_tester/get_overflow_render_flex_list_test.dart)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:hrk_flutter_test_batteries/hrk_flutter_test_batteries.dart';

void main() {
  group('getOverflowRenderFlexList()', () {
    const overflowFlexKey = Key('overflow_flex');
    final overflowFlexFinder = find.byKey(overflowFlexKey);

    // Doesn't work. See test/error/disable_overflow_error_test.dart
    // setUp(() {
    //   disableOverflowError();
    // });

    // Doesn't work. See test/error/disable_overflow_error_test.dart
    // setUpAll(() {
    //   disableOverflowError();
    // });

    // setUpAll(() {
    //   configureHrkLogging();
    //   packageLogger.level = Level.ALL;
    // });

    testWidgets('1', (tester) async {
      disableOverflowError();
      tester.view.physicalSize = Size(100, tester.view.physicalSize.height);
      addTearDown(() => tester.view.resetPhysicalSize());
      await tester.pumpWidget(const Row(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(width: 110),
        ],
      ));
      final overflowRenderFlexList = tester.getOverflowRenderFlexList();
      expect(overflowRenderFlexList.length, 1);
    });

    testWidgets('0', (tester) async {
      disableOverflowError();
      tester.view.physicalSize = Size(100, tester.view.physicalSize.height);
      addTearDown(() => tester.view.resetPhysicalSize());
      await tester.pumpWidget(const Row(
        key: overflowFlexKey,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(width: 10),
        ],
      ));
      final overflowRenderFlexList = tester.getOverflowRenderFlexList();
      expect(overflowRenderFlexList.length, 0);
      tester.expectNoOverflow();
    });

    testWidgets('2', (tester) async {
      disableOverflowError();
      tester.view.physicalSize = Size(100, tester.view.physicalSize.height);
      addTearDown(() => tester.view.resetPhysicalSize());
      await tester.pumpWidget(const Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 110),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 110),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ));
      final overflowRenderFlexList = tester.getOverflowRenderFlexList();
      expect(overflowRenderFlexList.length, 2);
    });

    testWidgets('of, 2', (tester) async {
      disableOverflowError();
      tester.view.physicalSize = Size(100, tester.view.physicalSize.height);
      addTearDown(() => tester.view.resetPhysicalSize());
      await tester.pumpWidget(const Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 110),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            key: overflowFlexKey,
            children: [
              Row(
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(width: 110),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(width: 110),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ));
      final overflowRenderFlexList = tester.getOverflowRenderFlexList(
        of: overflowFlexFinder,
      );
      expect(overflowRenderFlexList.length, 2);
    });

    testWidgets('of, matchRoot, 1', (tester) async {
      disableOverflowError();
      tester.view.physicalSize = Size(100, tester.view.physicalSize.height);
      addTearDown(() => tester.view.resetPhysicalSize());
      await tester.pumpWidget(const Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 110),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            key: overflowFlexKey,
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 110),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ));
      final overflowRenderFlexList = tester.getOverflowRenderFlexList(
        of: overflowFlexFinder,
        matchRoot: true,
      );
      expect(overflowRenderFlexList.length, 1);
    });
  });
}
```