# Flutter Widget test cannot emulate different screen size properly

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, testing, dart

Before deploying my Flutter app, I wanted to test it on multiple screen sizes to check if there is any `Renderflex overflow` for smaller screens.

But I when first modified the screen size during widget testing to match the device I was using during the development, I realized that the widget test is throwing `Render overflow` errors already, even though it did not have such errors on the real device. So I asked this questions [How to fix A RenderFlex overflowed during Widget Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62444634/how-to-fix-a-renderflex-overflowed-by-72-pixels-on-the-right-in-flutter)

But I after further investigation and using Flutter golden feature test which snaps png out of widget tests, I narrowed down the problem to a discrepancy in **text size**.

You can see clearly in the reproducible step below that the text during the widget text is **WAY BIGGER** (on the right) than the actual text in the real device (on the left).

[image]

The bigger text size during Widget test causes the `RenderFlex error` in my app.

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Now connect a real device and run this code with `flutter run`

`lib/main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: TextScaleComparaison(),
    ),
  );
}

class TextScaleComparaison extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final widget = Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
          final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
          final dpr = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
          final textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
          final vi = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets;
          final vip = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding;
          final font = DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.fontFamily;
          print("width is $width and height is $height and dpi is $dpr txtScale is $textScale vi is $vi vip is $vip font is $font");
          return Center(child: Text("This cannot be that long!!"));
        },
      ),
    );
    return widget;
  }
}
```

2. Check the logs and you should see device screen info:

For me I got :

`I/flutter (27450): width is 411.42857142857144 and height is 797.7142857142857 and dpi is 2.625 txtScale is 1.1 vi is EdgeInsets.zero vip is EdgeInsets(0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0) font is Roboto`

Copy the screen `width` and `height` to and `textScale` and `devicePixelRatio` to the next step in the code below.

3. Edit the code below to add the above setting because we want to simulate this exact screensize in the test.

`test/test.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:my_app/main.dart';
void main() {

  testWidgets(
    "Emulate real screen size",
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // Adjust these to match your actual device screen specs
      final width = 414;
      final height = 846;
      tester.binding.window.devicePixelRatioTestValue = (2.625);
      tester.binding.window.textScaleFactorTestValue = (1.1);
      final dpi = tester.binding.window.devicePixelRatio;
      tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(width * dpi, height * dpi);
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQueryData(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: TextScaleComparaison(),
          ),
        ),
      );
      await expectLater(
        find.byType(TextScaleComparaison),
        matchesGoldenFile("text.png"),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Run `test.dart` with `flutter test --update-goldens test/test.dart`

This will create a png file at `test/text.png`

Check the logs: For me it printed:

`width is 414.0 and height is 846.0 and dpi is 2.625 txtScale is 1.1 vi is EdgeInsets.zero vip is EdgeInsets.zero font is Roboto`

## What I am missing ? Why can't the text show exactly the same as the real device?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is because of the font difference used by `flutter test` and `flutter run`.

Flutter's default font is `Roboto` for Android if you did not change it other font.

1. Default  Android: `Roboto` font and for iOS: `San Francisco` font
2. Customize https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Either 1) or 2) these fonts are not available to `flutter test` by default.
Flutter test purposely uses a font called `Ahem` which is made out of square blocks that you see on your screenshot.

This is a preview:

[image]

`Ahem` font square are wayyy bigger than the normal that you are using. Therefore, it causes the `RenderFlex overflow error`

## Solution

To achieve a near perfect  emulation of your device in `flutter test` you have to download the font data then load the exact font that you are using.

To load a font in widget test, you should do inside the `testWidgets` function or `setUp`:

```
final flamante = rootBundle.load('assets/fonts/Flamante-Roma-Medium.ttf');
final fontLoader = FontLoader('FlamanteRoma')..addFont(flamante);
await fontLoader.load();
```

Then add this font to the `ThemeData` before pumping the widget.

```
 theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'FlamanteRoma',
 ),
```

The final test.dart code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:example/test/compare_test_size.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets(
    "Emulate real screen size",
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      final flamante = rootBundle.load('assets/fonts/Flamante-Roma-Medium.ttf');
      final fontLoader = FontLoader('FlamanteRoma')..addFont(flamante);

      await fontLoader.load();

      // Adjust these to match your actual device screen specs
      final width = 411.4;
      final height = 797.7;
      tester.binding.window.devicePixelRatioTestValue = (2.625);
      tester.binding.window.textScaleFactorTestValue = (1.1);
      final dpi = tester.binding.window.devicePixelRatio;
      tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(width * dpi, height * dpi);

      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQueryData(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: TextScaleComparaison(),
            theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'FlamanteRoma',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

      await expectLater(
        find.byType(TextScaleComparaison),
        matchesGoldenFile("text.png"),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Now re generate the golden test and check the png. You will see real text, not boxes anymore:

`test/test.png`

[image]

And don't forget to add the same font in your main.dart

```
runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: TextScaleComparaison(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'FlamanteRoma',
      ),
    ),
  );
```

And also don't forget to update `pubspec.yaml` and run `flutter pub get`

```
- family: FlamanteRoma
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Flamante-Roma-Medium.ttf
```

Comment: And as a quick hack you could just change the font-scaling to overcome more generic RenderFlex errors caused by the testing font, e.g. `tester.binding.window.textScaleFactorTestValue = (0.8);`

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work on Flutter 1.17.5 (nor 1.17.4, nor 1.20.0-7.3.pre-beta). I can do `flutter build bundle` and it fails if I change `pubspec.yaml` to non-existing path, so I'm confident that part is correct. Running `flutter test` fails with `Unable to load asset: assets/fonts/Flamante-Roma-Medium.ttf`. This is thrown in `PlatformAssetBundle.load` and I think that's the problem, it shouldn't be PlatformAssetBundle? Anything else that I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

As Curly already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447898/flutter-widget-test-cannot-emulate-different-screen-size-properly/62460566#comment111494711_62460566), you can overwrite the `tester.binding.window.textScaleFactorTestValue` with a lower value. `0.8` was working well for my used fonts, but depending on your setup, you might use even a lower value. In this way, you don't need to await the loading of your fonts in each test case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't necessarily want to store the font that you want to use in the test in `assets/` since it then will be bundled into the app, you can also store it directly in the test directory (or somewhere else) and read it with `File`.

So say that you have the following font:

```
test/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf
```

And then to use it:

```dart
final ubuntuRegular = File('test/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf');
final content = ByteData.view(
  Uint8List.fromList(ubuntuRegular.readAsBytesSync()).buffer,
);
final fontLoader = FontLoader('UbuntuRegular')
  ..addFont(Future.value(content));
await fontLoader.load();
pumpWidget(
  MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
    home: Scaffold(body: YourWidget()),
  ),
);
```

You could also make this into an extension since you'll probably repeat it a lot:

```dart
extension WidgetTesterExtension on WidgetTester {
  Future<void> pumpApp(WidgetBuilder builder) async {
    final ubuntuRegular = File('test/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf');
    final content = ByteData.view(
        Uint8List.fromList(ubuntuRegular.readAsBytesSync()).buffer);
    final fontLoader = FontLoader('UbuntuRegular')
      ..addFont(Future.value(content));
    await fontLoader.load();
    return pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
        home: Scaffold(body: Builder(builder: builder)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```