# How to resize app screen on `WidgetTester`? Need it to test the responsiveness of my widget

Tags: flutter

I have widget that act as a home layout. The layout is simple, its just a navigation bar on bottom for mobile and side for web. Thats why I need to test which nav bar are rendered based on those condition.

```dart
class HomeLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeLayout({
    Key? key,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth >= 600) {
          return _WideDeviceLayout(child: child); // render NavigationRail
        }

        return _ThinDeviceLayout(child: child); // render BottomNavigationBar
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I already trying to use `tester.view.physicalSize` to stub the tester view. It works on the first test, but the second test will fail because the `BottomNavigationBar` keeps rendered.

```dart
group('HomeLayout widget', () {
  group('on Thin Device (width < 600)', () {
    testWidgets('should render BottomNavigationBar', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(testWidget);

      tester.view.physicalSize = const Size(412, 915);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(
        tester.widget(_WidgetFinders.navBar),
        isA<BottomNavigationBar>(),
      );
    });
  });

  group('on Wide Device (width >= 600)', () {
    testWidgets('should render NavigationRail', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(testWidget);

      tester.view.physicalSize = const Size(1024, 600);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(tester.widget(_WidgetFinders.navBar), isA<NavigationRail>());
    });
  });
});
```

Before using the `tester.view.physicalSize` (just directly expect with just `pumpWidget`), the first test will fail and the second test will succeed. That means the tester default `Size.width` is above 600.

Is there something wrong on my test file?

Answer (score 0):

Its solved. I found it here: [Flutter Widget test cannot emulate different screen size properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62447898/19337625)

I just need to times the size with `tester.view.devicePixelRatio`.

```dart
group('HomeLayout widget', () {
  group('on Thin Device (width < 600)', () {
    testWidgets('should render BottomNavigationBar', (tester) async {
      final dpi = tester.view.devicePixelRatio;
      tester.view.physicalSize = Size(412 * dpi, 915 * dpi);

      await tester.pumpWidget(testWidget);

      await expectLater(
        tester.widget(_WidgetFinders.navBar),
        isA<BottomNavigationBar>(),
      );
    });
  });

  group('on Wide Device (width >= 600)', () {
    testWidgets('should render NavigationRail', (tester) async {
      final dpi = tester.view.devicePixelRatio;
      tester.view.physicalSize = Size(1024 * dpi, 600 * dpi);

      await tester.pumpWidget(testWidget);

      await expectLater(
        tester.widget(_WidgetFinders.navBar),
        isA<NavigationRail>(),
      );
    });
  });
});
```