# How to test a Flutter widget's intrinsic size

Tags: testing, flutter, widget

I have a custom text widget and I am trying to test that the widget has a certain intrinsic size for some text string.

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('MongolRichText has correct size for string', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MongolRichText(text: TextSpan(text: 'hello'),));

    final finder = find.byType(MongolRichText);
    expect(finder, findsOneWidget);

    // How do I check the size?
  });
}
```

How do I check the intrinsic size of the widget?

I'm not trying to limit the screen size as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706569/how-to-test-flutter-widgets-on-different-screen-sizes).

*I found the answer in the Flutter source code, so I am posting this as a Q&A pair. My answer is below.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `WidgetTester` has a `getSize` method on it that you can use to get the rendered size of the widget.

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('MongolRichText has correct size for string', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(Center(child: MongolText('Hello')));

    MongolRichText text = tester.firstWidget(find.byType(MongolRichText));
    expect(text, isNotNull);

    final Size baseSize = tester.getSize(find.byType(MongolRichText));
    expect(baseSize.width, equals(30.0));
    expect(baseSize.height, equals(150.0));
  });
}
```

**Notes:**

- Putting the custom widget in a `Center` widget makes it wrap the content. Otherwise `getSize` would get the screen size.
- I got the actual numbers by running the test and seeing what the actual values should be. They seemed reasonable (`MongolRichText` is vertical text), so I updated the test with the expected numbers to make the test pass.
- This solution was adapted from the [Futter Text widget testing source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/widgets/text_test.dart).