# How to deal with device width and orientation in widget testing?

Tags: flutter, widget-test-flutter

The widget that I want to test is dependent on the device width and orientation. Is it possible to set those parameters for a widget test, so that I can write a test for different devices sizes and orientations?

Comment: there is an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706569/how-to-test-flutter-widgets-on-different-screen-sizes