# How to test widgets integrity with increased font sizes from accessibility options?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

In my app, I've noticed some widgets generate overflow exception in a particular situation: when there are increased font sizes preempted by the user via Accessibility options in the iOS/Android.

I would like to widget test these widgets, by passing a parameter to increase the font size like OS selected, and check if there are any overflows.

This kind of test would be similar to [widget test in different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706569/how-to-test-flutter-widgets-on-different-screen-sizes), in which is possible to set the physical size like below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
(...)
  testWidgets('test overflow on iPhone SE 1 gen', (tester) async {
    tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(320.0, 568.0);
   (...)
}
```

Are there any recommended practices over widget testing with highly increased font sizes as an accessibility option in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 3.10.0, the window singleton is deprecated( https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton). Therefore, the textScaleFactor must now be set as follows:

`tester.platformDispatcher.textScaleFactorTestValue = 2.0;`

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a new MediaQuery when you pump your widget:

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
  home: Material(
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.5),
          child: YourWidgetHere(),
        );
      }
    ),
  ),
));
```

**Update:**

It may be more appropriate to update the test scale factor, although I haven't tested it:

```dart
tester.binding.window.platformDispatcher.textScaleFactorTestValue = 2.5;
```