# Setting window physicalSize and devicePixelRatio not working in futter test

Tags: flutter, dart

According to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706569/how-to-test-flutter-widgets-on-different-screen-sizes), I tried this in my test:

```
      import 'dart:ui' as ui;

      testWidgets('test', (tester) async{
          // setup the physical size
          tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = const Size(1366.0, 673.0);
          tester.binding.window.devicePixelRatioTestValue = 1.0;
    
          // reset the edited settings after the test ends
          addTearDown(tester.binding.window.clearPhysicalSizeTestValue);
          addTearDown(tester.binding.window.clearDevicePixelRatioTestValue);
    
          //////////// For debugging
          var physicalSize = ui. window.physicalSize; // debugger shows Size(2400.0, 1800.0)
          var pixelRatio = ui.window.devicePixelRatio; // debugger shows 3.0
          ///////////

          await tester.runAsync(() async {
            ... // code that depends on the screen size (window.size and window.devicePixelRatio)
          });

          ...
        });
```

##### Why is the physicalSize and pixelRatio not changing?

Comment: These are relatively new APIs, and we're supposed to use them. They seemed to work in one app, but now I'm trying it in another app and I cannot get them to do anything. The older APIs were never an issue with widget tests. What has happened?