# How to make Flutter tests ignore layout overflow messages?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I have some widgets inside of a fixed size SizedBox. These widgets don't overflow the SizedBox.

However, when I'm running tests, they do overflow, and the tests fail. I guess this is because tests don't really have fonts, and they estimate the space the fonts occupy. It estimates wrong and it overflows. How can I turn off the overflow error when testing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847569/how-specify-window-for-tests/53847974#53847974 mentions a few things that might be relevant. Screen size, font, ...